# UnitOfWork & Generic Repository, SOLID principles with Custom Repository

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, solid-principles

I'm using UnitOfWork and Repository patterns in my project. I'm trying to code clean.

This is my **IUnitOfWork.cs**  (Application Layer)

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    int Save();
    IGenericRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}
```

The implementation **UnitOfWork.cs** : (Persistence Layer)

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{      
    private readonly DBContext _context;
    private Hashtable _repositories;
    public UnitOfWork(DBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IGenericRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (_repositories == null)
            _repositories = new Hashtable();

        var type = typeof(T).Name;

        if (!_repositories.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            var repositoryType = typeof(GenericRepository<>);

            var repositoryInstance =
                Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType
                    .MakeGenericType(typeof(T)), _context);

            _repositories.Add(type, repositoryInstance);
        }

        return (IGenericRepository<T>)_repositories[type];
    }

    public int Save()
    {
        // Save changes with the default options
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    // etc.. Dispose()
}
```

My **IGenericRepository.cs** : (Application Layer)

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(object id);
    void InsertList(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
    // etc..
}
```

In my service : (Application Layer)

```
var result = UnitOfWork.Repository<Entities.Example>().Delete(id);
```

And using Unity, I inject the dependency in the container.

```
  container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
```

**And it works like a charm.**

Now I have a custom Repository `ICustomRepository`:

```
public interface ICustomRepository: IGenericRepository<Entities.Custom>
{
    void Test();
}
```

How can I access the `Test()` function using my `IUnitOfWork`?

```
var result = UnitOfWork.Repository<Entities.Custom>().Test();  // not working
```

**UPDATE**:

@Thomas Cook give me a way using cast :

```
   (UnitOfWork.Repository<Entities.Custom>() as ICustomRepository).Test();
```

I get a NullReferenceException:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Comment: HierarchicalLifetimeManager... that wouldn't be Prism would it? If so do yourself a favor and use a real DI framework like Autofac. FYI the EF DbContext is already a unit of work. Just create one in a using block and it's done. To be honest this looks kind of wrong to me.

Comment: Why aren’t you just leveraging Ef core dbcontext for handling unit of work? I feel like it’s unnecessary to create this whole hierarchy considering you can leverage something that already exists. Some of the best engineering involves not writing code unnecessarily

Comment: My ORM can be EF or Ado.net or something else

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to cast, because `UnitOfWork` `Repository` method returns a `IGenericRepository` which doesn't declare `Test`. So you'll need to cast the returned value to a `ICustomRepository` which inherits `IGenericRepository` and bolts on the `Test` method.

Comment: I get NullReferenceException using (UnitOfWork.Repository<Entities.Custom>() as ICustomRepository) :(

Comment: You need some registry for map `TEntity` to right `IGenericRepository` to make it work.  Some DI framework can be such registry but you can do it yourself of course.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst casting *would* work (if the repository wouldn't be null) you could ask yourself is this is useful; What good is an abstraction of you're going to depend on knowing its details, i.e.: the caller now *knows* it actually is a `non-generic` `interface` and `type`, namely a `ICustomRepository` (btw the reason you get the `null ref` probably is because `UnitOfWork` *only* creates the `generic` repositories and your custom repo doesn't exist).

A better (IMO) and more explicit way to design your `Unit of Work` *not* in a `generic` way but list all repositories:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    int Save();
    ICustomRepository CustomRepository {get;}
    IGenericRepository<Entities.Example> ExampleRepository {get;}
    // etc...
}
```

This way you don't need any casting *or* know its details.

Furthermore, I would recommend to *pass* all repositories to the constructor of the `UnitOfWork` from your *dependency injection* and don't make its responsibility too big.

```
public UnitOfWork(DBContext context, ICustomRepository customRepository ...)
    {
       //
    }
```

Just make sure you use *the same instance* of `DbContext` in your `Unit of Work` as the one that's injected into your repositories.